# will dt.rows.add() method always add row to the bottom of the datatable?

Tags: .net, datatable

Will the datatable.rows.add() method always add a datarow to the end of the datatable?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far I know, the  `datatable.rows.add()` adds new row to end of datatable.

If you want to insert the row at the first, you have to do like this:

```
dTable.Rows.InsertAt(dRow, 0);
```

Comment: :thanks...how to make sure that it will add to the end?Will there be any documentation available?

Comment: and one more thing is, will the dt.AcceptChanges reorder the datatable?

Comment: I don't have documentation to provide internal mechanism of add() method but I can  assure you that it would add the datarow at the end of datatable.....About dt.AcceptChanges, it does not reorder the datatable rather it just commit a change to the value of a column in the row....