# Is there a SQL statement that will break what would be 2 long columns into several pairs of columns?

Tags: sql, oracle, select, nested

I have data that, in a "normal" query, would appear like this:

```
Val1    Val2
----    ----
1   2
2   [blank]
3   2
4
5   1
6   3
..
96  1
```

What I want, though, is something like this (I need to limit the number of rows to 12):

```
Val1    Val2    Val1    Val2    Val1    Val2    ... Val1    Val2
----    ----    ----    ----    ----    ----
1   2   13  1   25  [blank]  ...    85  1
2   [blank] 14  1   26  3   ... 86  [blank]
..  ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...
12  1   24  [blank] 36  2   ... 96  3
```

Is there a select statement that would give me that? I'm no SQL expert, but I'm thinking something (semantically) along these lines:

```
select (select val1, val2 from dbtable where val1 < 13),
(select val1, val2 from dbtable where val1 > 12 and val1 < 25),
...
(select val1, val2 from dbtable where val1 > 84)
from dbtable
```

### UPDATE

In response to dfb's sql example:

When I do this:

```
SELECT t1.Val1, t1.Val2 FROM 
(SELECT Val1, Val2, rownum() as rownum FROM dbTable) t1 
INNER JOIN (SELECT Val1, Val2, rownum() as rownum FROM dbTable) t2 
ON t1.rownum/2 == t2.rownum/2
```

...I get *"FROM keyword not found where expected"*

And when I do this (remove the "rownum()" stuff):

```
SELECT t1.Val1, t1.Val2 FROM 
(SELECT Val1, Val2 FROM dbTable) t1 
INNER JOIN (SELECT Val1, Val2 FROM dbTable) t2 
ON t1.rownum/2 == t2.rownum/2
```

...I get *"ORA-01747: invalid user.table.column, table.column, or column 
specification"*

### UPDATE 2

Sully's example came the closest, although I wish the UNION SQL would work - it would be better if it could be done without pushing down the valid values. As it is, I have the right layout but the vals are not appearing just where I need them to within that 16X12 layout. At any rate, for posterity's sake, here's how the Rows and Columns are dynamically created (not as shown in the code below, and not identical to each other):

```
//prebuild 12 rows in outputDt 
int iRows = 12;
while (iRows > 0)
{
    DataRow row = outputDt.NewRow();
    outputDt.Rows.Add(row);
    iRows -= 1;
}

//prebuild 16 cols in outputDt 
int iCols = 16;
while (iCols > 0) {
    DataColumn col = new DataColumn();
    outputDt.Columns.Add(col);
    iCols -= 1;
}
```

### FINAL UPDATE

Got it working. See [Is it possible to populate a DataGridView with alternating vertical columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12065611/is-it-possible-to-populate-a-datagridview-with-alternating-vertical-columns)

Comment: Interesting problem...can I ask what the output is going to be used for? This seems to me like something that should be handled by formatting logic in your code, not SQL.

Comment: Yes if the column names will remain Val1 and Val2 for all the subsequent columns then its a formatting problem and should be handled at display logic. Otherwise you may need to read Pivoting techniques

Comment: @BLSully: This is to be presented in a DataGridView (C# Winforms). Presenting the data vertically is problematic. I think it would be much easier to just get the data in the desired form from the git-go.

Comment: @ClearLogic: I don't care about the titles/headers; in fact, they will be invisible; only the data itself should display in the DataGridView.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bonus to this is if you end up with more data, it'll just build more horizontal columns as needed but never go over 12 rows of data. The "in-SQL" way will require code changes if you ever need to display more data.

**Disclaimer**: This is totally off-the-cuff (C# as that's what I'm used to). There are probably much better ways to do this (Linq?) The logic should be pretty close, but this gives you the flexibility to use that list of data for other purposes than this very narrowly focused display.

```
DataTable dt = ResultsFromSproc();
DataTable outputDt = new DataTable();

//prebuild 12 rows in outputDt
int iRows = 12;
while(iRows > 0) {
    outputDt.Rows.Add(new DataRow());
    iRows-=1;
}

int outputColumn = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i+=1){
    DataRow dr = dt.Rows[i];

    if(i % 12 == 0 && i > 0) { 
        //add two more columns to outputDt
        outputDt.Columns.Add() //Not sure but you might need to give it a name. (outputColumn+2).ToString() should work
        outputDt.Columns.Add() //Not sure but you might need to give it a name. (outputColumn+3).ToString() should work
        outputColumn += 1;
    }
    outputDt.Rows[i%12][outputColumn] = dr[0];
    outputDt.Rows[i%12][outputColumn + 1] = dr[1];
}
//Step2: Bind to outputDt. Step 3: Profit!
```

**ALTERNATE version**: For requirement that val1 == 48 goes in cell 48 (see comments)

```
DataTable dt = ResultsFromSproc();
DataTable outputDt = new DataTable();

//prebuild 12 rows in outputDt
int iRows = 12;
while(iRows > 0) {
    outputDt.Rows.Add(new DataRow());
    iRows-=1;
}

int outputColumn = 0;
int iMaxCell = (int)dt.Select("MAX(Val1)")[0][0];
//ASSUMING YOU HAVE ALREADY DONE AN ORDER BY Val1 in SQL (if not you need to sort it here first)
for(int i = 0; i < iMaxCell; i+=1){
    DataRow dr = dt.Rows[i];

    if(i % 12 == 0 && i > 0) { 
        //add two more columns to outputDt
        outputDt.Columns.Add() //Not sure but you might need to give it a name. (outputColumn+2).ToString() should work
        outputDt.Columns.Add() //Not sure but you might need to give it a name. (outputColumn+3).ToString() should work
        outputColumn += 2;
    }
    //compare to i+1 if your data starts at 1
    if((int)dr[0] == (i+1)){
        outputDt.Rows[i%12][outputColumn] = dr[0];
        outputDt.Rows[i%12][outputColumn + 1] = dr[1];
    }
}
//Step2: Bind to outputDt. Step 3: Profit!
```

Comment: That might work, thanks. BTW, laziness was/is not the problem.

Comment: On "outputDt.Rows[i%12][outputColumn] = dr[0];" I get, "There is no row at position 0."

Comment: @ClayShannon: I didn't code out every single line... replace the `//prebuild 12 rows...` comment with a loop that iterates 12 times adding a DataRow to outputDt (See edits to answer in that area)

Comment: I think this is the right approach. Keep this table formatting logic out of the SQL code and rearrange it in C# before binding it to your data grid.

Comment: @BLSully: "System.Data.DataRow.DataRow(System.Data.DataRowBuilder)' is inaccessible due to its protection level" on calls to new DataRow()

Comment: @ClayShannon: GRRR...Sorry I don't write that kind of code often. See here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11662825/will-dt-rows-add-method-always-add-row-to-the-bottom-of-the-datatable

Comment: @ClayShannon: I found (and fixed) a few bugs, and added a few comments to my example code. Hopefully you get it working. Will check in tomorrow morning.

Comment: Okay, after adding code to create the 16 columns also, and changing "outputColumn += 1;" to "outputColumn += 2;" it works pretty well.

Comment: Glad that is working for you now. Apologize for the bugs... I wrote that on the fly and figured I would miss a few details.

Comment: Well, it's not exactly as I need it, because it fills the first cells, whereas I need it to "migrate" based on val1 (if val1 = 48, it should be placed in cell48, etc., and then val2 should go into cell 60 (next column over).

Comment: @ClayShannon: Check alternate version above. That should get you close

Comment: This line:

int iMaxCell = (int)dt.Select("MAX(Val1)")[0][0];

...errors out with "Filter expression 'MAX(Val1)' does not evaluate to a Boolean term.

...while this line (I added "SELECT" experimenting with trying to get it to work):

int iMaxCell = (int)dt.Select("SELECT MAX('Val1')")[0][0];

...errors out with "Missing operand after 'MAX' operator" (I also tried without the single quotes around Val1)

Comment: @ClayShannon: Looks like `Select` can't do it actually :( Here's the claimed fastest way http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2442525/how-to-select-min-and-max-values-of-a-column-in-a-datatable

Check this answer out...maybe you still can do it with `Select` http://stackoverflow.com/a/9414334/622129

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this this, but it's not pretty. The comments about doing this in a presentation layer are on point.

```
SELECT ... FROM
(SELECT v1,v2,rownum as rn FROM Foo WHERE mod(rownum,2)=1) t1
INNER JOIN (SELECT v1,v2,rownum as rn FROM Foo WHERE mod(rownum,2)=0) t2
ON (t1.rn/2 = t2.rn/2)
```

Comment: Thanks, but no go; I'll add my response above.

Comment: See if this works for you, this is the general idea - I fixed the syntax.  I can't get it to return properly for a SQLFiddle and don't have an Oracle instance.  I'll update once I receive an answer here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12079909/oracle-rownum-behavior-with-mod-function

Comment: What replaces the ellipsis dots? v1 and v2, IOW "SELECT v1,v2 FROM (..." ?

Answer (score 2):

if you know the Rows will always be 96 then this is one of the static Pivoting technique

```
select val1 AS col1, val2 AS col2,NULL AS Col3,NULL AS Col4 ,NULL AS Col5,NULL AS Col6,NULL AS col7,NULL AS Col8 from dbtable where val1 < 13
UNION 
select NULL AS col1,NULL AS col2 ,val1 AS Col3, val2 AS Col4,NULL AS Col5,NULL AS Col6,NULL AS col7,NULL AS Col8 from dbtable where val1 > 12 and val1 < 25
UNION
select NULL AS col1,NULL AS col2 ,NULL AS Col3, NULL AS Col4,val1 AS Col5,val2 AS Col6,NULL AS col7,NULL AS Col8 from dbtable where val1 > 25 and val1 < 37
.....
...AND So ON
```

And if the number of rows are unknown then you needs to do Dynamic Pivoting.

Note: above syntax is for SQL Server 2008, I hope it wont be different for Oracle.

Comment: I think this is very close (but no "cigar" yet); this gives me the needed number of columns (16 actually, not 8 - I extended the example), but has 264 rows (it needs to be 12). The vals in cols 3 and 4 don't begin until row 13, the vals in cols 5 and 6 don't begin until row 25, etc. Is there a way to eliminate the empty cells so that all returned vals display in the 12 rows?

Comment: IOW, the data returned is right, I just need the empty/null cells to "go away" - to "pull up" the populated "cells" to the top.