# Oracle rownum behavior with mod function

Tags: sql, oracle

Given

```
CREATE TABLE Foo(v1 integer, v2 integer);

INSERT INTO Foo VALUES (1,2);
INSERT INTO Foo VALUES (3,4);
INSERT INTO Foo VALUES (5,6);
```

and

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Foo WHERE mod(rownum,2) = 0;
```

returns 0 rows, where it should return 1

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT mod(rownum,2) z FROM Foo) tt WHERE z=0;
```

returns 1 rows

What am I missing here?  I don't see anything in the [ROWNUM](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/pseudocolumns009.htm) or MOD docs suggesting any ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ROWNUM returns the row number of the actual query, not of the table the query is base on. So `SELECT COUNT(*) ...` returns one row with rownumber 1 with `mod(rownum,2) != 0`, which is then discarded by the WHERE caluse, effectively returning no rows at all.

A (unfiltered) subselect returning a rownumber as column can help. The WHERE clause is then applied to the outer select.

Comment: I understand it's not based on the base table, but is this statement correct? - ROWNUM is evaluated row by row, not applied to entire `SELECT ... FROM ...` set and then filtered in the where clause?

Comment: @dfb, yes, that essentially the case.  The doc you linked on ROWNUM explains the example of a query with the condition `ROWNUM > 1`: "The first row fetched is assigned a ROWNUM of 1 and makes the condition false. The second row to be fetched is now the first row and is also assigned a ROWNUM of 1 and makes the condition false. All rows subsequently fail to satisfy the condition, so no rows are returned."  The ROWNUM values are assigned row-by-row, then checked against any conditions on ROWNUM, and when rows are rejected, the same ROWNUM value is assigned to the next candidate row.

Answer (score 9):

[`ROWNUM`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/pseudocolumns009.htm) is not assigned until you query, so you will not be able to use it in a `WHERE` clause like that.

You can do the following:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM
(
  select v1, v2, rownum rn
  from Foo 
) f
WHERE mod(rn,2) = 0;
```

The `ROWNUM` is the row's position ins the result set, and it is evaluated after the records are selected.

These types of queries will never work:

```
WHERE ROWNUM > x
WHERE ROWNUM BETWEEN x AND y
```

But this will work

```
WHERE ROWNUM < x
```

Since you are wanting to evaluate the `rownum` with the `mod` function it will not work because the `rownum` is not available at that point. This is why, you would have to place it in a sub-query to use the `mod` function.